Centre viewport on screen — Godot 4.1
I'm using Godot 4.1 and exporting to mobile (Android).
I want the viewport to be centred in the device screen, with aspect set to expand to allow overflowing things to be visible.
Here are my Project Settings:

But here is how it looks on the device (the content part is at the top in red). If it were centred, there would be equal parts yellow at the top and bottom of the content.

